# Should I force MS SQL to consume x amount of memory?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I'm trying to get better performance out of our MS SQL database. One thing I noticed that the instance is taking up about 20 gigs of RAM, and the database in question is taking 19 gigs of that 20. Why isn't the instance consuming most of the 32 gigs that is on box? Also the size of the DB is a lot larger then 32 gigs, so it being smaller then the available Ram is not the issue. I was thinking on setting the min server memory to 28 gigs or something along those lines, any thoughts? I didn't find anything on the interwebs that threw up red flags on this idea. This is on a VM(VMWARE). I verified that the host is not overcommitting memory. Also I do not have access to the host.

This is the query I ran to find out what each database was consuming

```
SELECT  DB_NAME(database_id),
COUNT (*) * 8 / 1024 AS MBUsed
FROM    sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY    database_id
ORDER BY    COUNT (*) * 8 / 1024 DESC
```

Comment: I normally just open the Task Manager and see if there's memory available.

Comment: is this a VM or physical server?

Comment: Task manager performance shows the all of the memory is being used, but the processes tab doesn't show that. What I see in the processes tab is that SQL server is only consuming 3 GIG! What I have seen my sql query is the best way to find out how much memory is being used.

Comment: There are a lot of memory consumers in SQL Server that your query does not consider. e.g. plan cache. What does `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` show?

Comment: DBCC MEMORYSTATUS is only showing VM COMMIT as 4.9GB sigh...

Comment: And what's the page life expectancy? Is it possible that it isn't using any more because it doesn't need to? It hasn't had to read the vast majority of pages yet.

Comment: FYI, the "min server memory" does not allocate the memory when you set it. It only says to the server: When you pass the min threshold, please keep at least that amount of memory from now on. In my opinion, your server does not need the memory because like Martin Smith says, pages are staying in memory long enough so SQL can reuse the space.

Answer (score 0):

If data is sitting on disk, but hasn't been requested by a query since the service has started, then there would be no reason for SQL Server to put those rows into the buffer cache, thus the size on disk would be larger than the size in memory.

Comment: Trust me, that is not the issue in my ENV.